reverse proxy motion jpeg camera stream using lighttpd
I have an rtsp camera stream I convert to a motion jpeg stream using ffmpeg-server.
ffmpeg-server provides the motion jpeg stream under http://localhost:8090/still.jpg and http://localhost:8090/live.mjpg
I want to proxy this stream using lighttpd so that it is availible at http://localhost:8080/live.mjpg (note the port change)
my lighttpd config has a proxy entry and I can get the still.jpg but not the live.mjpg.
$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/still.jpg)" {   
  proxy.server = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "localhost", "port" => 8090 ))) 
}
$HTTP["url"] =~ "(^/live.mjpg)" {
    proxy.server = ( "" => ("" => ( "host" => "localhost", "port" => 8090 ))) 
}


OK http://localhost:8090/still.jpg
OK http://localhost:8090/live.mjpeg
OK http://localhost:8080/still.jpg
FAIL http://localhost:8080/live.mjpeg

I'm not sure, but what I think is happening is that lighttpd is recieving the request and forwarding it correctly, howeverm because the request to the backend never completes,the response is never forwarded to the client. Is there a way to asklighttpd to forward the response in small chunks as available?

Turns out you can use an option to stream the response data.
server.stream-response-body = 2

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_stream-response-bodyDetails
